# Included standard libraries not found by ARM cross-compiler

Tags: linux, arm, embedded, cross-compiling

I'm trying to do cross-compilation for an ARM a8 processor. I'm moving the code base to a new system, and therefore it should be installed using the same compiler and makefiles as the original system.

I know that I'm using a arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc compiler.

I've installed the following packages:

```
> sudo apt install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
> sudo apt install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

When I compile the following code block:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// filename: simple.c

int main(void)  
{
  printf("I'm printing!\n");
  return;
}
```

with this command:

```
> arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc simple.c
```

I expect it to compile at this step. I instead get:

```
In file included from simple.c:1:0: 
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I guess you have to install `libc6` libraries, like [here](https://www.acmesystems.it/arm9_toolchain). `apt-get install libc6-armel-cross libc6-dev-armel-cross` etc.

Comment: I added those libraries as specified in those instructions. The same result as what is listed in my questions occurred.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end? I'm faced with the same issue...

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are missing is the multilib packets, if I'm right, this should do the trick for you.

```
sudo apt install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```